# Managing transitive dependencies in OSGI?

Tags: java, osgi, bundle, apache-karaf

I'm trying to build a simple REST service to learn OSGI. I am using Spark Servlet to handle the requests.

I embedded spark core as a dependency, built my project in maven and got a wiring package error in Karaf upon deployment.

It seems like I follow package after package, one by one to resolve each error and it takes about 2 hours just to resolve the dependencies. Clearly I'm doing something wrong..

How should I go about doing this so I can use spark servlet?

Comment: No code snippet, no error message...

Answer (score 0):

The primary idea of OSGi is to create reusable modules. Massive transitive dependencies indicate that someone did not get the message.

If you find yourself in your situation then it is an indication you're in a mess. Now, plenty of people clearly live in that mess because they're oblivious of a better world, where you get reuse and things work out of the box.

A simple rule is that on the application parts (which should be really small) you can use whatever you want since it will never be reused. However, I would go out of my way to limit dependencies on libraries that have transitive dependencies because, imho, they always cause more problems in the long run then that they deliver in the short run.

Using OSGi with large transitive dependencies is paying a lot of money and not getting any benefits.

Comment: That's the problem I faced with OSGI: there is no running away from libraries. And libraries always have transitive dependencies.

Comment: True. But GOOD libraries have few. Regardless of OSGi, my experience is that when developers thought about their dependencies it is a very strong indication that their code is better.